# Facebook - cannot upload file using the <input type="file"> tag

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to let the user upload an image from my facebook app using the following php

```
<?php
echo render_header('Your');

define("MAX_SIZE", "1536");

function getExtension($str){
  $i = strpos($str,".");
  if(!$i) {return "";}
  $l = strlen($str) - $i;
  $ext = substr($str, $i+1, $l);
  return $ext;
}

$errors = 0;

if(isset($_POST['Upload'])){
  $image = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
  if($image){
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    if((strcasecmp($extension,"jpg") != 0) && (strcasecmp($extension,"jpeg") != 0) && (strcasecmp($extension,"png") != 0) && (strcasecmp($extension,"gif") != 0))
    {
      $errors = 1; 
    }
    else{
      $size = filesize($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);
      if($size > MAX_SIZE*1024){
        $errors = 2;
      }
      else{
        $image_name = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $extension;
        $newname = "../images/" . $image_name;
        $flName = "/images/" . $image_name;
        $copied = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $newname);
        if(!$copied){
          $errors = 3;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

if(isset($_POST['Upload']) && $errors == 0){
  //add to database here
  ...
  if($errors == 0){
    include "uploadedFile.php";
  }
}
else{

$user_details = $fb->api_client->users_getInfo($user, 'first_name,last_name,pic_square');
$image_url = $user_details[0]['pic_square'];
if($image_url == ""){
  $image_url = "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/pics/q_silhouette.gif";
}
$user_name = $user_details[0]['first_name'] . " " . $user_details[0]['last_name'];
if(isset($_POST['Upload']) && $errors == 0){
?>
<div id="error" class="error">
<h2 id="standard_error" name="standard_error">Failed to upload tattoo.</h2>
<p id="standard_explanation" name="standard_explanation">
Error uploading file. This error occurred because either the photo was a size we don't support or there was a problem with the image file.
<br/>
</p>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
<div id="newalbum" align="center">
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" action="" method="post">
<table class="formtable" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="tallrow">
<td class="label">
Upload Image:
<br/>
<small>
You can upload
<br/>
JPG, GIF or PNG
<br/>
files.
</small>
</td>
<td>
<div id="files">
<div id="1">
<input id="file1" class="inputfile" type="file" name="file1" size="22"/>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="formbuttons">
<input id="" class="inputbutton" type="submit" value="Upload Tattoo" name="Upload" />
<br/>
<small>The file size limit 1.5 MB. If your upload does not work, try uploading a smaller picture.</small>
<br/>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

But when I execute this code and the user presses the "Upload" button, the value of $_FILES['file1']['name'] comes out to be blank.

Is this code permissible in Facebook apps? If not what is the correct way to upload files?

Thanks

**Edit**

Ok so the problem is with facebook. They strip out all file tags from any request! It is suggested that we use iframes instead!

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Found the problem. Facebook strips all file tags before sending in a request. The solution is to use iframes instead.

Comment: Heh. I was about to tell you that. I had the same problem with my own app. I think the problem is that regular app pages get filtered through FB, and they don't want to let users upload files to their servers then have to pass the files to your server.

Comment: Can someone ellaborate on this? Does this mean setup the app as an "iframe" vs a "fbml" in the app settings space, or does this mean call a <fb:iframe src=""> for the entire page? Or just for the form? I'd love do have this problem solved for me, too!

Comment: You can just put the HTML containing the form inside an iframe. Thats how I got it working.

Comment: I just got it working too, but inconclusively as to why. I have an (Code Igniter, incidentally) app setup as an iframe (as opposed to FBML) that uploads files. Form is setup normally. A good explanation here: http://www.ccheever.com/blog/?p=10 about the communication methods and what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to access the file name, try this...

```
switch ($_FILES['file1']['error']) {
  case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
   echo '<p class="warning">File Upload Failed! File too large.</p>';
   break;
  case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
   echo '<p class="warning">File Upload Failed! File exceeds limit.</p>';
   break;
  case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
   echo '<p class="warning">File Upload Failed! Please try again.</p>';
   break;
  case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
   echo '<p class="warning">File Upload Failed! No temp directory.</p>';
   break;
  case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
   echo '<p class="warning">File Upload Failed! Failed to write to disk.</p>';
   break;
  case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
   echo '<p class="warning">File Upload Failed!</p>';
   break;
}
```

This should tell you where the problem lies.

Comment: Also, this can't hurt at the top:
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
Take it out when it goes properly live.

Comment: tried this. It doesn't go into any of the switch cases. so there are no errors :( Is there some restriction with using file inputs in facebook?

Comment: MSpreji, I tried adding this statement, it gives the error "Undefined index: file1". Why would it do that?! I have a file input type with the name "file1"

Answer (score 0):

Your html-markup doesn't have a form end-tag.

```
<form>

</form>
```

Also, your form's action should either point to itself or that page that handles the image processing (In your case, the same file)

```
<?php
echo("<form id=\"formid\" name=\"formid\" method=\"post\" action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\"

</form>");
?>
```

Comment: Added both these. But I still get an error when using the ini statement MSpreji had mentioned - Undefined index:file1

Comment: Try a simple test then. Create your form with 1 file field, 
and after posting, use print_r($_FILES) to see if info is passed or not. 

If this even this doesn't work, there's a server setting that's furking things up.